# MATLAB: OOP Calling Functions from Different Class

Tags: c++, matlab, class, oop, matlab-class

My goal is to design a re-usable engine programmed in MATLAB using MATLAB OOP. This is my first attempt to do this. My problem that I would like to resolve is the following: I have an abstract class `cPayoffBase` that defines the interface for an unknown type payoff. Inheriting `cPayoffBase`, I have a concrete class `cPayoffCall` which implements a call option. Now I defined another class `cVanillaDerivs` that takes in an user-defined payoff object and a strike price. When I pass in the user-defined object to `cVanillaDerivs` to calculate some quantity an exception `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` surfaces. I shall provide the codes in detail.

cPayoffBase.m

```
classdef (Abstract) cPayoffBase < handle

    methods (Abstract)
        mfGetPayoff(argSpotPrc)
    end

end
```

cPayoffCall.m

```
classdef cPayoffCall < cPayoffBase

    properties (GetAccess = private, SetAccess = private)

        dmStrikePrc

    end

    methods

    function obj = cPayoffCall(argStrikePrc)

        obj.dmStrikePrc = argStrikePrc;

    end

    function rslt = mfGetPayoff(obj, argSpotPrc)

        rslt = max(argSpotPrc - obj.dmStrikePrc, 0.0);

    end

end
```

cVanillaDerivs.m

```
classdef cVanillaDerivs

%% Data Members
properties (GetAccess = private, SetAccess = private)
    dmPayoffObj
    dmExpiryDt
end

%% Implementation
methods

    % Constructor
    function obj = cVanillaDerivs(argPayoffObj, argExpiryDt)

        obj.dmPayoffObj = argPayoffObj;
        obj.dmExpiryDt  = argExpiryDt;

    end

    % Member Functions
    function rslt = mfGetExpriyDt(obj)

        rslt = obj.dmExpiryDt;

    end

    function rslt = mfGetDerivPayoff(argSpotPrc)

        rslt = obj.dmPayoffObj(argSpotPrc);

    end
end
end
```

command window

```
>> clear classes
>> spot = 100; strike = 50; T = 1;
>> payoffObj = cPayoffCall(strike);
>> typeVanilla = cVanillaDerivs(payoffObj, T);
>> mfGetDerivPayoff(typeVanilla, spot)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in cVanillaDerivs/mfGetDerivPayoff (line 37)
            rslt = obj.dmPayoffObj(argSpotPrc);
```

In C++, given that I have a wrapper class and wrap the class object `cPayoffBase` I can do something like `return (*dmPayoff)(dmSpotPrc)` for double returning function `mfGetDerivPayoff(double dmSpotPrc) const` in class `cVanillaDerivs`. Please kindly let me know my errors and if possible how can I achieve the same process in MATLAB OOP like C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access element number 100 of the property `dmPayoffObj`. However, this property is set to `payOffObj`, which isn't an array. Thus the error.

What I think you wanted is return the Payoff of `dmPayoffObj`. You should change the method `mfGetDerivPayoff` of the class `cVanillaDerivs` as follows:

```
function rslt = mfGetDerivPayoff(argSpotPrc)
    rslt = obj.dmPayoffObj.mfGetPayoff(argSpotPrc);
end
```

Comment: Ah. so need `.` to call the function `mfGetPayoff()` is needed. All that question writing for a great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `rslt = obj.dmPayoffObj.mfGetPayoff(argSpotPrc);` instead of `rslt = obj.dmPayoffObj(argSpotPrc);`?

Comment: Yes the problem and solution that you and @Christian provided worked. Thank you.